# create azure package with build

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I was just upgrading my project from sdk 1.3 to 1.7 and I noticed that now when I build the application the package(cspkg) is not created with the build. I have go click on publish to create a package. Is there a way to tell VS to create a package everytime a build is triggered.

Also using msbuild is there a way to do the same thing. I have multiple projects under a solution, Most of which are just libraries and then there is this azure app. Is there a way to specify a single msbuild statement with params to tell the azure app to create the package as well as build the other projects. Also when I specify debug the debug package should be created and when I specify release switch the release package should be created.

How could I do the same thing on my build server as well where I have a .proj file which specifies the sln to build. How could I mention a switch to build the package there.

Thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure CSPACK command (Be sure to have CSPACK.exe launched from SDK 1.7 Path otherwise you will get some schema related errors with SDK 1.6 project) as Post Build event in your Windows Azure Application Build settings. This way when you will build, after successful build CSPACK command will run and package your application. Same way you can configure your MSBuild configuration. I just tested and it worked for me.

Visit [this MSDN article on packaging a cloud service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-model-and-package/#servicepackagecspkg) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using msbuild as well. See the Resolution section of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18117994/746754).