# How to package a "Azure Cloud Service" as part of a build

Tags: visual-studio, azure

So I have a "Windows Azure Cloud Service" project in a solution.

Now I can right click and "Package" this project to produce a cspkg.

How do configure the solution to build that  cspkg on every release build?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513425/create-azure-package-with-build